# A function such that $f(x) > x f'(x)$.

Tags: analysis

Any help? I thought about solving the differential equation $f(x) = x f'(x)$ but I don't think that does anything useful.

Comment: Try $f(x)=2$, then $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Any non-constant functions?

Comment: Try $f(x)=\begin{cases}3 & x<1\\4-x & 1<x<2 \\ 2 & x>2\end{cases}$.  Smooth at the corners if you like.

Comment: Say $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is concave, $f^{\prime\prime}<0$ what can you say?

Comment: f'(x) tends to 0? Not following you Sergio, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well solving the differential equation isn't entirely useless. The solutions of it are of the form
$$f(x) = a x, \qquad a \; \text{a constant}$$

Now add any positive constant $b$ to that function to get
$$f(x) = ax + b$$
motivated by the fact that differentiation on the right hand side will kill the constant. Now we have
$$f(x) = ax + b, \qquad x f'(x) = ax$$
and $ax + b > ax$ follows as long as $b > 0$

Comment: Perhaps you mean "as long as $b\gt0$".

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the ODE:

$f(x)=xf'(x)\Rightarrow \ln f(x)=\ln x+C\rightarrow f(x)=x+C$ let $C=1$

so $f(x)=x+1\gt x(f'(x))=x$